# put partly transpared photo on top of panorama

Tags: gimp, images, transparency, image-quality, rgb

What is it nessesary to do if I want to see just black edges from background image in image placed on top?

Here are links to source images
[image: <a href="http://oi65.tinypic.com/xbzvhk.jpg">panorama</a><br>]
[image: <a href="http://oi65.tinypic.com/29kvuvp.jpg">photo</a>]

This is what I want to create:

[image: <a href="http://oi63.tinypic.com/29maskz.jpg">Here</a>]

You can see there are edges from background panorama mountains in picture on top.
Any ideas, please?

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you want to achieve. Can you give us a sketch of desired result?

Comment: To put things in one place I edited this question with relevant information from your previous post. We can then delete your previous question (or, after an account merge you can also do that yourself).

Comment: @Takkat thank you for edditing my questions! And don't you know how to solve it, please?

Comment: I am too busy  with work at the office to guide you. If I understood it correctly you wanted to paint black outlines of mountains from the rendered source panorama on top of the destination photo?

Comment: Yes, you understand it well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Hide the second layer
- Make the first layer grayscale
- Use edge detection filters to highlight edges of the background landscape
- Adjust levels and invert if necessary to get thin black lines on white background
- Show the second layer and switch it to MULTIPLY mode